# Android 4.1 FLAVOR and BUILD_TYPE issue

Tags: android, gradle, android-build-flavors, android-build-type

I updated to Android studio 4.1, and the build variant tab became different.

Instead of offering my app and its module choice of build, it duplicated twice the app.

I didn't think much of it and ran Flavor A with release build. To my surprise, it ran Flavor B with debug build.

For the sake of testing, I tried disabling the Flavor B, delete the .idea folder, sync with gradle, rebuild and run for it to finally run Flavor A. And it comes back to flavor B after 1 run, even if it doesn't exist.

For the build type, it's worse, I can't run release, it only runs debug no matter what I select.

Of course I tried commenting debug and so and so. impossible to run release.

Has anyone experienced the same issues ? Any solution on how to fix this ?

Comment: for me as 4.1 is completely broken: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=build%20variant